# VBA to find the font color of a string

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I am new to VBA..I am writing a macro for some file comparison..My requirement is if a string has red color font,that string should be ignored for iteration and code should move to next iteration..I have tried the following code.

```
Dim compare = {"test1","test2","test3",.....etc}

i=0

For j=1 to Ubound(compare)    
  j=1

  If compare.Characters(j,Len(compare(i))).Font.Color <> vbRed Then    
    ' Some Code
  End If

  i=i+1    
Next
```

However during the execution I am getting runtime error 424 "Object Required.Please help me to complete this task

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This will only work with characters in a cell.

Comment: Is there any way to do this?

Comment: your string compare , is just a string, it cant have colour , so you cant do this.  you need to reference a cell

Comment: Strings don't have a Font, so maybe youngest I add more code, paticularly how you populate `compare`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Say we have cells **A1** thru **A4** like:

[image: pic]

Then this code will find the non-red characters:

```
Sub ColorTest()
    Dim I As Long, J As Long
    For I = 1 To 4
        For J = 1 To Len(Cells(I, 1).Value)
            If Cells(I, 1).Characters(Start:=J, Length:=1).Font.Color <> vbRed Then
                MsgBox "non-red found at cell A" & I & " position " & J
            End If
        Next J
    Next I
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

May I assume that the source for your data is an excel-sheet (as pointed out by previous comments, a pure string does not hold information on colours), and for one reason or another you want to use an array. Then this might be a way to solve the problem (prerequisite: full string is in one colour only)

(Just saw that there's a solution provided by Gary's student without using arrays as well...AND providing for cases where only part of the string is red...nice one!)

```html
Sub colour()

Dim arr_DB As Variant
Dim i As Long

ReDim arr_DB(1, 1)  'Array size to be adjusted as needed, Base 0 !

For i = 1 To 2
    arr_DB(i - 1, 0) = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value   'Value of Cell
    arr_DB(i - 1, 1) = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Font.Color  'Colour of Font in Cell

Next

If arr_DB(i - 1, 1) = 255 Then   ' No. 255 is colour RED

    'skip.....

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks everyone :)..I have made changes as per above comments and it is working fine..