# Macro to change colors of specific characters in a range

Tags: vba, excel

I wanted to develop a macro for my worksheet that would pick up a range and change the color of specific chars based on its color. This was [similarly answered before here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26949079/vba-to-find-the-font-color-of-a-string/) and I took Gary's Student code as the basis for my script. It worked, but I have noticed a little problem that I couldn't solve.

When I have a cell that already starts with a value with a different color than the pattern, it only changes the first character to the color I want, and changes the rest of the chars and words next to it to the pattern. It only happens in this case, for others cells starting in black (pattern) it works perfectly.

Ex.: Suppose that the italic characters are *red* (color that I want to change), bold characters are **blue** (color to substitute red) and the rest is the automatic color (black):

Cell value before applying macro: *This is* a value.
Cell value after applying macro: **T**his is a value.

I have searched for it and got no success.
Could it be an Excel bug or an error in the script?

See my version of the code below:

```
Sub ColorChange()
   Dim I As Long, J As Long, K As Long 'I = Rows, K = Columns, J = Chars
   For K = 6 To 8 'For columns F to H
       For I = 2 To 200 'For rows 2 to 200
           For J = 1 To Len(Cells(I, K).Value)
               If Cells(I, K).Characters(Start:=J, Length:=1).Font.Color <> vbAutomatic Then
                   Cells(I, K).Characters(Start:=J, Length:=1).Font.Color = RGB(226, 107, 10)
                   Cells(I, K).Characters(Start:=J, Length:=1).Font.Bold = True
               End If
           Next J
       Next I
   Next K
End Sub
```

Comment: You can only change the color of sub-strings of text in a cell if the total length of all of the text in the cell is less than 257 chars. This is a known bug in Excel. Are your text values less than 257 chars?

Comment: Can you post the sample data and result?

Comment: @ExcelHero Do you have a documentation about that "known bug"? In what version? I tried it in my Excel 2007 with a string of over 700 chars and it worked perfectly.

Comment: The bug is in 2013. I think (but not 100% certain that it is in 2010 as well). I do not have documentation but I've reported it to MS.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? I tried the code in my Excel 2007 and it worked properly as expected. Can you clarify your description of the problem (the second paragraph)? It's not very clear to me. Maybe some examples will help.

Comment: @mumumurilo: My problem - when I originally started to format characters in a cell differently - was that I forgot to check if the cell really consists of text **only** `If Cells(I, K).Value = Cells(I, K).Formula then` (otherwise it obviously cannot work). Just a memory from the past...

Comment: @ExcelHero I'm using Office 2013, but I have noticed that the "bug" happens in cells that are less than 257 chars too.

Comment: @RacilHilan I intended to upload examples but as I'm a new user it won't let me upload... I will update the second paragraph to be more clear.

Comment: It is working properly for me in Excel 2007. I don't have 2013 to test. Your code is only changing the to one color (brown), so id you're saying that it changes the other characters to another color (black), then it's not your code. Maybe a bug (I don't think so) or some other code. Create a new file and copy this function to it so you can test it without any possible interference with another code.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly there is no such colour index (well… *color* index) as `vbAutomatic`; rather, you would need to use `xlAutomatic` (-4105) to represent the Automatic colour option.

Secondly, the `Color` property of `Font` will return an RGB value representing your chosen colour (0=black, 2<sup>24</sup> – 1=white) instead of the index of the option you chose. I surmise that you're after the `ColorIndex` property, although checking for `Color=0` would probably be wiser: the *Black* font colour option doesn't have Index -4105, but Index *1*.

Thence, the updated `J` loop:

```
       For J = 1 To Len(Cells(I, K).Value)
           If Cells(I, K).Characters(Start:=J, Length:=1).Font.Color <> 0 Then
               Cells(I, K).Characters(Start:=J, Length:=1).Font.Color = RGB(226, 107, 10)
               Cells(I, K).Characters(Start:=J, Length:=1).Font.Bold = True
           End If
       Next J
```

Comment: Very good points, but I don't think that will change anything. VB does implicit conversion to match the two different types when it reaches `...Color <> vbAutomatic`, so it converts `vbAutomatic` to `Long` and gives it the value 0. This end result is identical to your code `Color <> 0`. Having said that, I fully agree with your points and how the code should be.

Comment: That's a good point regarding the conversion. You can probably tell I use variants sparingly. As for undeclared variables, the `Option Explicit` directive at the top of a code module will prevent these from being entered.

Comment: Yup, using `Option Explicit` is a must :-). I've never programmed in VB without it.

Comment: @AdamFrederickWiseman Thanks for your answer. The end result was identical here too. The weird thing is that the code works, the error happens only when the cell already starts with different colors.

Comment: @Mumumurilo Did you see my last comment? It is working properly for me in Excel 2007. I don't have 2013 to test. Your code is only changing the to one color (brown), so if you're saying that it changes the other characters to another color (black), then it's not your code. Maybe a bug (I don't think so) or some other code. Create a new file and copy this function to it so you can test it without any possible interference with another code.

Comment: @RacilHilan Sorry, didn't have time to test it before. I have tested with a new and clean file without any additional code and it keeps changing only the first char.

Comment: Post this "new file" so we can download it and test it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I had formulas in the cells.  After I copied/pasted them as values, I had no problems with my macro.