# how can I detect an cell content color?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel cell.
In the cell, I have few paragraphs, each paragraph using different font color.
How can I get the font color value for each paragraph using VBA?

Comment: Sorry, the following web page inspire me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26949079/vba-to-find-the-font-color-of-a-string

Comment: That should of told you how to do it :)  Post the code you tried.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav It's "should have", not "should of", please.

Comment: @teylyn thought this was a VBA forum, not a grammar forum.

Comment: In written communication, grammar matters. Many visitors here don't have English as their first language and may struggle with such sloppy writing. No code would forgive you such a syntax error. So please show English the same respect.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, the web page describe how to detect the content color in a given cell character by character:

```
sheetName = "sheet1"
Set sheet1 = Worksheets(sheetName)
Set theCell = sheet1.Range("G18")
text = theCell.Value

For i = 1 To Len(text)
    If (theCell.Characters(Start:=i, Length:=1).Font.Color = vbBlack) Then
       '....... if the character is in black, do normal procedure
    else
       '........if the character does not in black, handle the exceptional case
    end if 
next
```